# Using the MediaStream API to capture screenshots or share live screens in javascript?

Tags: javascript, screenshot, mediastream

I have recently been working on a project that requires me to capture a screenshot of the clients machine at certain events (uncaught exception etc).
Having explored html2canvas, I can tell you that I am NOT looking for a DOM reader/renderer library. (too many dirty canvas elements on page)
I was wondering if it was possible to actually use the screen as a mediastream source in the new API, and capture images (for eg: in PNG format)
Found no mention of it in : https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#stream-api

Ideas anyone?

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/ not yet implemented anywhere, and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture only available at `chrome:` level (extensions/plugins)

Comment: thanks a ton man!.. already looked at these two, just wanted confirmation that these are the only options.

Comment: @Kaiido - actually I am having issues with html2canvas and cross-domain tainted canvas elements.
are there any workarounds for that?

Comment: Apart from a proxy no, no workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins/programs are the only options for now if you really want to capture native.

Comment: actually I am having issues with html2canvas and cross-domain tainted canvas elements.
are there any workarounds for that?

Comment: @ArunavaRoyChoudhury Do you mean it gives error for iFrames and stuff from other sites? That's quite complex. I'm building my own web-proxy and put that in an iFrame so I can browse to every site. Sites like google block their site for cross-domain calls.